# Showing that subset is not part of subspace involving unit vector

Tags: linear-algebra

$
\{ \vec x  \in \Bbb R^3: \vec x \cdot \vec n = 0\}  
$
where $\vec n $ is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^n$

Determine if the subset of $\Bbb R^3 $ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$

What I tried is showing the vector addition $(\vec x \cdot \vec n) + (\vec w \cdot \vec n) = 0 $

It seems like this would fail for all values where w is not the zero vector?

Comment: You misunderstood the subspace conditions. It says in particular, that if $x$ and $w$ are in the space, then so is $x+w$. What does it mean that $w$ is in the space?

Comment: You write $(\vec{x}\cdot \color{red}{\vec{w}})+(\vec{w}\cdot\vec{n})=0$.  I hope this is a typo and that you meant to write $(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{n})+(\vec{w}\cdot \vec{n})=0$.  This should be justified why and reiterated that this is equal to $(\vec{x}+\vec{w})\cdot \vec{n}$ to make it clear why it is being discussed and its purpose for appearing in your proof.  As for "*this would fail for all values where $w$ is not the zero vector*" surely not.

Comment: Consider for example $\vec{n}=(0,0,1)$.  Then your set is the set of all vectors who are orthogonal to $(0,0,1)$... including but not limited to $(1,0,0)$ or $(0,1,0)$ and in general your set could have in this example be rewritten as $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)~:~x_1,x_2\in\Bbb R,~x_3=0\}$.  Your original problem is an important one to understand and it will appear again later by the name [Orthogonal Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement).

Comment: So the unit vector can be written as the three vectors (1,0,0) (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) giving three cases?

Comment: No.  There are infinitely many unit vectors.  It could just as well have been the case that $\vec{n}=(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2,0)$ or something else entirely.  Any vector whose length is $1$ can be a unit vector.  It so happens that here we are told that $\vec{n}$ is something specific that will not change throughout the problem and we are not told anything else about $\vec{n}$ apart from that it is a unit vector.  The problem then further defines the set in question, noting that every element in your set is such that they are orthogonal to $\vec{n}$, whatever $\vec{n}$ was

Comment: Reworded with plain speech rather than symbols... the question asks if it is true that if you have some original vector $\vec{n}$... if you take two vectors who are both perpendicular to $\vec{n}$ and add them, will the result also be perpendicular to $\vec{n}$?  If you take a vector who is perpendicular to $\vec{n}$ and stretch or scale it, will the result also be perpendicular to $\vec{n}$?  Is there necessarily at least one vector that will be perpendicular to $\vec{n}$?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation It makes more sense now. I still struggle to understand. Are we looking to find at least one vector w where the vector addition holds? Or will it hold for any vector w. Similarly if we want to disapprove the condition do we need to just find one case where vector w does not hold

Comment: If we wanted to disprove the condition, just one example would suffice.  Here we want to prove the condition and so we need to show it holds for *all possible* pairs $x,w$ in the set.  The proof will vary depending on how exactly you have the dot product defined and what you already know about it, and whether the three properties mentioned by @QuantumSuperfield are part of the definition, already known, or still need to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that $\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3:\vec{x}\cdot\vec{n}=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, you need to use the following basic properties of the inner product:

(i) $\vec{0}\cdot\vec{x}=0$ for every $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$;

(ii) $(\vec{x}+\vec{y})\cdot\vec{z}=\vec{x}\cdot\vec{z}+\vec{y}\cdot\vec{z}$ for all $\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}\in\mathbb{R}^3$;

(iii) $(\lambda\vec{x})\cdot\vec{y}=\lambda(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^3$.